# Manually (mathematically) signing and verifiying a file using RSA [Solved]

Tags: rsa

It is only recently that I entered cyber security field.. and one of the main foundations is nothing but Cryptography. Something which always fascinated me was the 'Chain of Trust' which is holding on crucial Mathematical theories on which robust protocols such as TLS are built.

I decided to demystify this subject by going through TLS and starting with breaking down the RSA crypto system process in a low level manner as to demonstrate the two formulas of encryption and decryption.

Below is a blog post I followed as a guide which I found very helpful however I could not match the end resulting hashes and therefore prove the whole concept.

I have done multiple troubleshooting to figure out where the anomaly is and the only thing I could notice is that when comparing the signature file computed by openssl and the signature value computed Mathematically using python, the values differ in a way that each 2 bytes are flipped as shown below:

[image]

[image]

I have modified the bash/python script in a way that the variables are exported from bash to python environment so that one could run the script in one go without having to paste separate code sections individually.

I really appreciate if you could point out anything I might be missing. It will be quite an accomplishment for me if I could demonstrate this concept.. as it will serve as the basis for other systems which build on it.

Update: Code now works fine. Tested on Ubuntu (Windows Subsystem for Linux)

Below is my script: [updated]

```
# rsa sign and verify a file using openssl and mathematically using python

# Create a file containing all lower case alphabets
echo abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz > myfile.txt 

# Generate 512 bit Private key, this includes both private and public key
openssl genrsa -out myprivate.pem 512

# Separate the public part from the Private key file.
openssl rsa -in myprivate.pem -pubout > mypublic.pem

# Cat the contents of private key
cat myprivate.pem

# Sign the file using sha1 digest and PKCS1 padding scheme
openssl dgst -sha1 -sign myprivate.pem -out sha1.sign myfile.txt

# Dump the signature file, -C is used to present the hex signature in little endian form
hexdump -C sha1.sign

# Verify the signature of file
openssl dgst -sha1 -verify mypublic.pem -signature sha1.sign myfile.txt

shasum -a 1 myfile.txt

PADDING=0001ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff00
ANS1_SHA1_MAGIC=3021300906052b0e03021a05000414
SHA1_HASH=`shasum -a 1 myfile.txt | cut -d ' ' -f1`
exp_PADDED_HASH=$PADDING$ANS1_SHA1_MAGIC$SHA1_HASH
echo $exp_PADDED_HASH
export exp_PADDED_HASH

openssl rsa -in myprivate.pem -text -noout

# Store the output of private key info in a variable
PRKEY_INFO=`openssl rsa -in myprivate.pem -text -noout`

# Grep and format string to output Modulus. Grep with -A is selecting the search result starting from start of match (modulus):
# tail -5 is selecting the piped string starting from the end and counting the number of elements as specified (in this case 5)
MODULUS=`echo "$PRKEY_INFO" | grep modulus: -A 5 | tail -5`
exp_MODULUS=`echo $MODULUS | tr -cd [:alnum:]`
echo $exp_MODULUS
export exp_MODULUS

# Grep and format string to output privateExponent
PREXP=`echo "$PRKEY_INFO" | grep privateExponent: -A 5 | tail -5`
# translate command will delete the complement of all letters and numbers which results in removing all colons : and spaces leaving only the hex value
exp_PREXP=`echo $PREXP | tr -cd [:alnum:]`
echo $exp_PREXP
export exp_PREXP

python
import os
padded_hash = int(os.environ["exp_PADDED_HASH"], 16)
# Convert modulus (calculated in step 3) to integer
os.environ["exp_MODULUS"]
modulus = int(os.environ["exp_MODULUS"], 16)
modulus
# Convert private exponent (calculated in step 3) to integer
os.environ["exp_PREXP"]
private_exp = int(os.environ["exp_PREXP"], 16)
private_exp

# Sign the message: (padded_hash ** private_exp) % modulus
# (a**b)%c is efficiently caluclated by pow(a, b, c)
sign = hex(pow(padded_hash, private_exp, modulus))[2:]
sign

# Format and the signature
slist = list(sign)
for i in range(len(sign) - 2, 0, -2) : slist.insert(i,' ')

slist[len(slist) - 48 : 0 : -48] = ['\n']*(len(slist)//48)
print("".join(slist))

quit()

openssl rsa -pubin -inform PEM -text -noout < mypublic.pem

PBKEY_INFO=`openssl rsa -pubin -inform PEM -text -noout < mypublic.pem`
MODULUS=`echo "$PBKEY_INFO" | grep Modulus: -A 5 | tail -5`
echo `echo $MODULUS | tr -cd [:alnum:]`
# Grep to print public exponent
echo "$PBKEY_INFO" | grep Exponent:
# sha1.sign is the signature file sent along with data file. Apart from deleting all complement of numbers and letters, the cut command will delete the first 9 charaters in each line 
signature=`od --endian big -x sha1.sign | cut -c 9- | tr -cd [:alnum:]`
echo $signature
export signature

python
import os
signature = int(os.environ["signature"], 16)
signature
modulus = int(os.environ["exp_MODULUS"], 16)
modulus
# Set the public_exp
public_exp = 65537L
# Convert sign to hash: (sign ** public_exp) % modulus
# (a**b)%c is efficiently caluclated by pow(a, b, c)
padded_hash = hex(pow(signature, public_exp, modulus))
padded_hash
padded_hash[-41:-1]
```

References:

https://medium.com/@bn121rajesh/rsa-sign-and-verify-using-openssl-behind-the-scene-bf3cac0aade2

Comment: What exactly you need? Do you want that smb. reviews your code? Do you want that smb. explain you something?

Comment: `hexdump` without arguments outputs two-byte chunks in *little endian*. (That is, each pair of bytes indeed appears swapped compared to the actual order in the file.) Try `hexdump -C`.

Comment: I can discern no on-topic question. Everything seems about tools or [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), which are off-topic. Or perhaps the format of `padded_hash` is not correctly (or at all) taken into consideration; but that's in the [definition of RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf#page=31].

Comment: @yyyyyyy thank you for the insight. I will read on the topic. At least now I have a ‘checkpoint’ and know that till that stage code and logic is correct. Will continue troubleshooting the rest of the code.